# Does a [Weapon] Of Spell storing's spell crit if the attack does?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, critical-hit

If I am wielding a [Weapon of Choice] Of Spell Storing, and I hit, I can cast the spell as an immediate action, and from what I understand, It just auto-hits, as if it used my attack roll.

Now, If I roll to hit and crit, does the spell I cast come out as a critical as well?

Does it only crit on a natural 20, or does it use the weapons crit range?

If that's the case, do I have to declare I am discharging the spell before or after the confirmation roll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

There are two crucial reasons why.

1. **The weapon casts the spell *after* the damage from a successful attack has been dealt.** The attack has no effect on the spell other than triggering the *spell storing* ability.
2. **The weapon casts the spell directly on the damaged target with no further attack roll needed.** The ability's text says the weapon "immediately cast[s] the spell on that creature," which affects the creature as if the spell was immediately cast on them and therefore needs no attack roll. One could argue a touch spell cast with a *spell storing* weapon needing an attack roll. However, the rules for touch attacks say that with spells/effects with a range of touch, "the aggressor need only touch a foe for such an attack to take full effect." No attack roll is needed because the weapon is already touching the creature. Without an attack roll, the spell cannot critically strike.

## *Spell storing* casts a spell from an item.

Remember that *spell storing* uses the rules for casting spells from items as noted in the [Using Items](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems.html#using-items) section of the Magic Items chapter in the core rulebook. The weapon itself casts this spell when damaging the creature. This is pointed out in the ability's text.

> Anytime the weapon strikes a creature and the creature takes damage
>   from it, the **weapon can immediately cast the spell** on that creature as
>   a free action if the wielder desires. (This special ability is an
>   exception to the general rule that **casting a spell from an item** takes
>   at least as long as casting that spell normally.) Once the **spell has
>   been cast from the weapon**..

Many people erroneously compare *spell storing* to spellstrike. *Spell storing* does not work the same way as the spellstrike magus class feature. That class feature uses the rules for holding touch spell charges whereas *spell storing* uses the rules for casting spells from items.

Comment: I think this answer makes more sense, however re-reading the spell storing enchantment, It casts the spell after damage is already dealt. You may want to edit your first point to reflect that its not just the attack roll, but damage as well.

Comment: Point #2 can be argued both ways, I dont think we can claim wether it works or not without evidence.

Comment: I think from looking at the rules on touch attacks, "the aggressor need only touch a foe for such an attack to take full effect.", assuming the aggressor is the weapon, and the spell is being cast as a result of damage, which is a result of physical contact, Id say its safe to assume the touch is already occurring. But I do agree, a snippet referencing that would be nice to see in the answer.

Comment: @Erudaki spells can fail before you have the chance to make a touch attack (if they are counterspelled, for instance). A *raw* reading suggests you would have to make another check if this spell is a touch spell, since the ability does not mention anything about it. A developer commentary is required when we can only guess the intent of the author.

Comment: Revised the second bullet point in response to feedback.

Comment: @Cyrad you are assuming the spell is cast **through** the weapon, like the magus [spellstrike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/#TOC-Spellstrike-Su-) ability. But nowhere it says such a thing. It says "*you can cast the spell*", while spellstrike says "*this melee attack deals its normal damage as well as the effects of the spell*" We are only guessing the author's intent here.

Comment: But there are other conditions to cast a spell succesfully. Are your hands free? Do you have your divine focus at hand? Do you have reagents available? Could you normally use a weapon attack to deliver  a touch spell like a magus? The ability (as written) is ambiguous, which has prompted [several unanswered threads](http://paizo.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Store.woa/wa/search?q=spell+storing+crit&what=messageboards) at paizo messageboards.

Comment: @ShadowKras My answer already points out that spellstrike and *spell storing* do not use the same rules. The text explicitly says the weapon casts the spell and references rules for casting spells from items.

Comment: Your answer would be greatly improved if that information was clarified (with links and quotes). But I still believe that a developer commentary is necessary there.

Comment: @ShadowKras I have added more information as requested. Developer insight isn't necessary as the ability clearly points out this uses the rules for casting spells from magic items.

Comment: Furthermore the spell has to be cast into the weapon, using any material components at the time of casting. Furthermore it is the weapon casting the spell, at the wielders will " the weapon can immediately cast the spell on that creature as a free action if the wielder desires." So it doesnt make sense for the wielder to have to cast the spell, as that would make it akin to a scroll (or some sort of spell completion item), requiring the user to cast a spell and have a UMD check if they cant cast the spell.

Comment: Adding to what Erudaki says, a magic item is not a spell completion item unless the item's description explicitly says so. *Spell storing* just a basic spell cast from an item except the weapon casts it as a free action. The rules are very clear on how those work.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **No.** The weapon crit has no bearing on spell crit.

From my reading of the rules, after the damage has been applied from your weapon roll you are **casting a spell from an item** as mentioned in the description from Ultimate Equipment, for the Spell Storing magic weapon special ability (emphasis mine):

> A spell storing weapon allows a spellcaster to store a single targeted spell of up to 3rd level in the weapon. (The spell must have a casting time of 1 standard action.) Anytime the weapon strikes a creature and the creature takes damage from it, the weapon can immediately cast the spell on that creature as a free action if the wielder desires. (This special ability is an exception to the general rule that **casting a spell from an item** takes at least as long as casting that spell normally.)

As you are simply casting a spell using an item, you should follow the standard rules for Spells and Critical Hits, which specify that "A spell that requires an attack roll can score a critical hit. A spell attack that requires no attack roll cannot score a critical hit. If a spell causes ability damage or drain (see Special Abilities), the damage or drain is doubled on a critical hit." So if you store a 3rd-level or lower targeted spell which does not require an attack roll (such as Magic Missile), then you do not roll and it cannot crit; however, if you store a targeted spell that also requires an attack roll, then it would be capable of a critical hit as described; otherwise, no critical hit would be threatened.

Unless I am reading them incorrectly, the rules as written seem to allow some odd interplay in which you could conceivably hit with your weapon but miss with your spell; for example, you could store a Shocking Grasp spell in your weapon, successfully hit and deal damage with the weapon, then roll and miss the melee touch attack required for the Shocking Grasp even though your weapon is at that moment touching the target. If you dismiss this as nonsensical (as has been suggested in the comments to this answer), then you are left with ALL stored spells being incapable of Critical Hits since none would ever require an attack roll.

Potentially related: any feats you have that might otherwise be applied to the stored spell, such as Spell Focus or a metamagic feat will not modify it at the time of discharge; however, in the absence of any contravening rule you should be able to apply them at the time of charging so long as the adjusted spell level remains 3rd or below.

Comment: The only problem I have with this reading is,  the spell storing enchantment specifies that the creature must take damage from the weapon, I dont see why you would have to make a separate touch attack when the weapon is quite literally already touching (quite painfully) the target, as it is dealing damage. It would make no sense for the weapon to hit, but a touch spell inside to miss. If you can clarify, or back up your answer with other rule references, I will reconsider my stance.

Comment: @Erudaki Not all targeted spells require rolls; for example, Magic Missile is targeted. But any spell that can critical (referencing OP's question) must also be a spell that can miss, because only spells that require rolls can critical as per the Core Rulebook: "A spell that requires an attack roll can score a critical hit. A spell attack that requires no attack roll cannot score a critical hit." I agree it doesn't make much sense, but that seems to be the RAW. If we just assume that no roll is needed, then it's just a flat no.